# Chebyshev's Inequality on symmetric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

For a symmetrically distributed random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, I want to get an upper-bound for $P(X \ge t)$ with Chebyshev's Inequality.

The problem is that $t < \mu$. I can only derive $P(X \ge t) = P(\mu - X \le \mu - t) = 1 - P(\mu - X \ge \mu - t) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} P(|X - \mu| \ge \mu - t)$, but applying Chebyshev's Inequality to the last step gives a lower-bound instead of an upper-bound.

Is it correct that Chebyshev's Inequality cannot be used to obtain an upper-bound in this case?

Comment: It's symmetric about the mean, unless you have $\mu = 0$ I'm not sure what you expect to get from Chebychev, as that is inherently a statement about deviation from the mean.

Comment: @AdamHughes Hmm, I see it now. What difference could $\mu = 0$ make?

Comment: At that point $P(X>t) = {1\over 2} P(|X|>t)$ and you can use Chebychev in the usual way.

Comment: @AdamHughes But now $t$ would be negative and Chebyshev would be inapplicable.

Comment: Why would $t$ be negative? In this case $t\ge 0$ would be the case for this to be the case, in fact that's built into the equality I put in my last post

Comment: @AdamHughes Sorry if I wasn't clear; $t < \mu$ is a condition given in the question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949296/one-sided-chebyshevs-inequality