# Chebyshev Inequality - one sided chebyshev

Tags: probability, inequality

How to prove the one-sided Chebyshev's inequality which states that if X has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then for any positive number $a > 0$ , the following inequality holds:

$P(|X-\mu| \leq -a)  \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$.

Is this similar to [One sided Chebyshev's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949296/one-sided-chebyshevs-inequality) . However does the same proof hold with

$P(|X-\mu| \leq a)$ as stated in the question versus $P(|X-\mu| \geq a)$ as per the link with the right hand side remaining same in both cases.

Comment: Would this $|X-\mu|\le a \iff -a \le X-\mu \le a\iff (-X+\mu\le a \wedge X-\mu \le a)$ work?

Comment: I am not sure if the stated problem for the inequality  is actually possible but i am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: You have not defined $\mu$. Usually it means $E[X]$ in this context, but you have clearly stated, that $E[X] = 0$...

Comment: I updated the question now please let me know...